# SQL Server DateTime - Timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

if I insert a data with `datetime` and the database server was set to automatically adjust clock for `Daylight Saving Time`, is there any chance the date value would be converted to adjusted daylight saving time?

Comment: why don't you write the short TSQL needed to test this?

Comment: i just wanted to know if ever there are stackoverflowers there encountered the same. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL server 2008 or above, and worried about that, you can change to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime